# Intersection of all open 'oversets'

Tags: general-topology

Consider a subset $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{V}=\{V\subseteq \mathbb{R} | V\space\text{is open and} A \subseteq V\}$. Suppose $V_0 = \bigcap_{V\in\mathcal{V}}V$ is open. Can we conclude $A$ is open? My intuition tells me $A$ is open, even more so, it tells me $A=V_0$ but I can't seem to find a proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly we have $A \subseteq V_0$.

To see that also $V_0 \subseteq A$, note that for every $x \notin A$ we have $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{x\} \in \mathcal{V}$, whence it follows that $x \notin V_0$.

This is not particular to subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, we have
$$A = \bigcap \bigl\{ V : A \subseteq V, V \text{ open}\bigr\}$$
in all spaces where singleton sets are closed (these are the $T_1$-spaces), for example in all metric spaces.